# How to get Lat/Long between start and end coordinates and spaced at equal distance?

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude

Suppose I have two GPS points (start and end points) each with lat/lon. I want to get equally spaced GPS points between start and end nodes. That is, I want to find GPS points  for example every 10 meter from start node to end node.

Similar question is asked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157693/getting-all-vertex-lat-long-coordinates-every-1-meter-between-two-known-points/262280#262280?newreg=43942ba298ad42fea4a6b95c35cd85b4).
From the answers given I have referred the one by Vikram Gupta. This solution works fine but if you replace

```
int dist = (int) d / interval
```

by

```
int dist = (int) d
```

in getLocations(...) method some calculated coordinates lay beyond the end coordinate. How can the code be modified to prevent this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  All questions should be standalone. You can reference another question, but the question itself should be a coherent whole. Please [Edit] this question so that it clear enough that someone else could answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer. Add the following method,

```
   public static boolean nodeInBetween(Node start, Node end, Node
 newNode) {
        if (start.getLatitude() < end.getLatitude()) {
             if (newNode.getLatitude()>end.getLatitude()) {
                return false;
            }
         } else if (start.getLatitude() > end.getLatitude()) {
             if (newNode.getLatitude() < end.getLatitude()) {
                 >return false;
            }
        >} else if (start.getLongitude() < end.getLongitude()) {
            if (newNode.getLongitude() > end.getLongitude()) {
                return false;
            }
         } else if (start.getLongitude() > end.getLongitude()) {
             if (newNode.getLongitude() < end.getLongitude()) {
                 return false;
             }
         } 
         return true;
     }
```

and modify part of for loop of the getLocations(...) method as follows

> ```
>         if (nodeInBetween(start, end, newNode)) {
>             coords.add(newNode);
>         } else {
>             break;
>         }
> ```

Note that:
MockLocation Class is named Node (with getLatitude() and getLongitude() mehtods) in this code

Comment: How do you make the nodes 'equal distance'?

Comment: Let me explain it using counter example. Suppose the start =1 and end = 10. You want to get all points from start to end 2 units apart (i.e. equal distance). The algorithm displays 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10. Therefore, here equal distance can be interpreted as equal intervals (the last interval may less than others)