# Getting latitudes and longitudes in between start and end coordinates and spaced at equal distance

Tags: python, coordinate-system, csv, latitude-longitude, python-3

I have a csv file which has the latitude and longitudes values , I need to find the coordinates in between the start and the end latitude and longitude which must be equally spaced at the interval of 10 meters.(to refer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157693/getting-all-vertex-lat-long-coordinates-every-1-meter-between-two-known-points/262280#262280?newreg=43942ba298ad42fea4a6b95c35cd85b4))

The csv file is as follows:

```
 id latitude longitude
  0   2.456     4.566
  1   3.457     6.455
  2   4.890     7.787
  3   5.679     9.852
```

From the given csv the start lat and long values are of id 0 and end coordinates are of id 1 .then for second time the start coordinates must be of id 2 and the end point must be of id 3 and so on. These must iteratively take the values from the csv and find the in-between coordinates from the start and end latitude and longitude values.

The output must be in this format:

```
 latitude longitude in_between_lat in_between_lon
   2.456     4.566     2.456          4.566
                       2.466          4.576
                       2.476          4.586
                       2.486          4.596
   3.457     6.455     3.457          6.455
   4.809     7.787     4.809          7.787 
                       4.819          7.797
                       4.829          7.807
   5.679     9.852     5.679          9.852
```

From these we can conclude  the in-between coordinates between start point 2.456, 4.566 and end points 3.457,6.455 and so on (here the values taken for the in-between lat and long are random).

Answer (score 1):

```
import geopandas as gp
import shapely
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

#your original data
d = [(2.456,4.566),
(3.457,6.455),
(4.890,7.787),
(5.679,9.852)]

#making a dataframe and then geodataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=['LAT', 'LON'])
gf = gp.GeoDataFrame(df)

#create a shapely point feature from lat and lon
gf['point'] = gf.apply(lambda x: shapely.geometry.Point(x['LON'], x['LAT']), axis=1)

#create following point needed by shifting rows
gf['shift_point'] = gf['point'].shift(-1)

#drop end row without a next value
gf = gf.dropna()

#create a line between current point and next point
gf['line'] = gf.apply(lambda x: shapely.geometry.LineString([x['point'], x['shift_point']]), axis=1)

#set crs and then covert to projected coordinate system as we'll be dealing meters
gf.crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'}
gf = gf.set_geometry('line')

gf = gf.to_crs(epsg=3857)

gf.plot()

#get the length of the line value
gf['length'] = gf.line.length
gf['length_10'] = gf['length'] / 10

#iterate through the dataframe, bad practice but hey ho
#here we generate a point on each line, that is "lp" distance along the line
#this lp value increases with each iteration
#the range amount will be dependent on the length of the line / by the step size
#every step the interpolation will increase by 10
#append the indexes and point values to lists

ix = []
basket = []

for i,r in tqdm(gf.iterrows()):
    lp = 0
    for v in range(0, 10 + 1):
        lp += r.length_10
        ix.append(i)
        basket.append(r.line.interpolate(lp))

#we then create another dataframe from these two lists and then join back onto the original line dataframe on the index
joined = gf.join(pd.DataFrame({'interpolations':basket}, index=ix))
joined = joined.set_geometry('interpolations')
joined = joined.to_crs(epsg=4326)
joined.plot()

joined['int_x'] = joined.interpolations.x
joined['int_y'] = joined.interpolations.y

joined = joined[['LAT', 'LON', 'int_x', 'int_y']]
joined.to_csv('path.csv')
```

[image: First .plot() to show lines]

[image: Points set at a much more distant interpolation than 10m, to get an idea]

Comment: i dont want the plot for the coordinates,I need the in-between cordinates to be saved in the csv.@saph_top

Comment: can u help me with these @PMK

Comment: @arpita the plots were really for demonstrative purposes. all the points are in the dataframe. edited the code so its saves to csv

Comment: It provides me the coordinates but does not consider the radius of the earth while iproviding the in-between cordinates, can u help me with these .....@saph_top

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157693/getting-all-vertex-lat-long-coordinates-every-1-meter-between-two-known-points/262280#262280?newreg=43942ba298ad42fea4a6b95c35cd85b4     @saph_top

Comment: The cordinated which we are getting are very large it must divide it into just 10 parts .........@saph_top

Comment: @arpita "I need to find the coordinates in between the start and the end latitude and longitude which must be equally spaced at the interval of 10 meters."

Comment: yes.....@saph_top

Comment: Did u found any solution ........@@saph_top

Comment: @arpita try the edited code, total length of the line is divided by how many sections your want, then an increase of lp is made in the loop of length_10 value.

Comment: ya it works .....but the loop takes the values of id 0-1 then 1-2 and then 2-3 ........the loop should process the values of  id as 0-1 then 2-3 then so on @saph_top

Comment: As apecified in the output format above @saph_top

Comment: @arpita I think I've done enough. These are fairly simple edits to make now, so learn some python and do it yourself. You haven't enamored me into doing any thing more.